# Error gpg: skipped "Username <email>": No secret key while trying to commit

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have this error while trying to commit code on VS code:

```
gpg: skipped "Username <email>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thank you very much.

This is my first time trying to use Git, so I'm very unfamiliar with the entire thing.